# JQuery Bootstrap Modal Window somehow reload/clears the parent fields in Ruby on Rails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

My problem is when clicking OK in the modal window, which goes to javascript function in the modal will reload or clear the parent fields ?

Here is the use case:
1. enter name string into parent name form input
2. click on Test Modal Button
3. a modal window appears
4. click on the modal window "OK" button. (with the cancel button its not a problem)
5. parent name input was cleared. Possibly the parent was reloaded.

I'ved created a simple rails project with a generated scaffold Post name:string. Nothing special but I just enabled bootstrap js and css.
https://github.com/axilaris/bootstrapmodal/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js
https://github.com/axilaris/bootstrapmodal/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

And then, I inserted this code into _form.html.erb, you can view it here:
https://github.com/axilaris/bootstrapmodal/blob/master/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb

```
<div id="windowCreateInvoiceProductDialog" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="windowTitleLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h3>Please enter a new product</h3>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="divDialogElements">
                    Code:<input class="xlarge" id="xlInput" name="modal_code" type="text" />
                    <br>
                    Name:<input class="xlarge" id="xlInput" name="modal_name" type="text" />
                    <br>
                    Description:<input class="xlarge" id="xlInput" name="modal_desc" type="text" />
                    <br>
                    Price:<input class="xlarge" id="xlInput" name="modal_price" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="okClicked ();">OK</a>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="divButtons">
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#windowCreateInvoiceProductDialog" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Test Modal Button</a>
            </div>          

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#windowCreateInvoiceProductDialog').bind('show', function () {
            //  document.getElementById ("xlInput").value = document.title;
                });
            });
        function okClicked () {
            $('#windowCreateInvoiceProductDialog').modal('hide'); 
        //  document.title = document.getElementById ("xlInput").value;
        //  closeDialog ();
            };


        </script>
```

Comment: I hope no one answers like this by making the OK button into this <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">OK</a> . What I really want is that Im able to catch ok button, do postprocess and either close the modal or leave it. closing the modal should not reload the parent page

Answer (score 0):

found the answer!

instead of this

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" >OK</a>
```

replace with this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="okClicked ();">Save changes</button>
```

and thats all to it, and its flexible, i could hide, not hide and do something.